# How to get the dimension of a function return value without evaluating the function

Tags: python, function

Assume I know that the function `f` returns a vector of unknown dimension. The function returns value of the form: `np.array(list)`. **Can I get the dimension of the return value *without* evaluating the function**?

Consider for instance this function:

```
def f(x):
    f1 = x**2
    f2 = x
    return np.array([f1,f2]);
```

I want some something like: `dim(f)` that gives the answer 2.

Right now I get around the problem by evaluating the function for a random  number and then find the dimension: `len(f(np.random.rand()))`
but I want to avoid the evaluation of the function.

`np`is off course `numpy`

Comment: what is x data type?

Comment: Numeric, always

Comment: so, if it is always numeric e.g. float then you know that the return array is 1x2 always.

Comment: @naivepredictor First sentence of the Q, in case it was missed: "_Assume [...] that the function f returns a vector of unknown dimension_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Koen Dercksen said is correct, there is no way to determine the dimension of the result without evaluating the function. However, if you do evaluate the function, you should use the [`.shape` property](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) instead of `len()`

For example:

```
def f(x):
    f1 = x**2
    f2 = x
    return np.array([f1,f2]);

len = f(0).shape[0]
```

Also generating a new random number for the function call is unnecessary, you can pass a constant as the parameter and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The output dimension of the function is dependent on that of its input, it's not static. You can reason about it yourself, in your example the function has an output dimension of `[2, *x.ndim]`. Sure, if `x` is a single scalar the dimension will be two, but if `x` is an array the dimension is gonna be different, et cetera.

In short, if you know your function always takes a scalar or some other value with static dimensions, just put its output dimension in the doc-string. If you take arguments that can be any dimension, you won't get around evaluating the function to find out the dimension of its result.